# What does "be raised' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, verbs

This context comes from the movie "Ford Vs Ferrari"

"We've only minutes of racing
left here at Daytona, a pitched battle for the
lead **is being raised** as The number 98 Ford makes an
incredible late surge."

**"raise"**
16. to bring to an end; remove: to raise a siege; raise a ban.(source:Collins English Dictionary)

**"raise"**
10. to give rise to; cause or provoke: to raise a smile.(source:Collins English Dictionary)

Comment: I haven't seen the film, but "being raced" would make more sense in this context.

Answer (score 0):

"Raise" does not correlate with "battle", so it's likely the announcer is speaking extemporaneously and put words together that just don't make sense.

"Raise" does correlate with "battle *cry*", however, and the announcer may have been thinking about that, and used the word "raise" where it didn't belong.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound particularly idiomatic or eloquent to state that a battle for the lead is "being raised" (at least in this context), but, be that as it may, I'm pretty sure definition (10) that you found ("to give rise to; cause or provoke") is the intent of the script here. That is, the late surge is causing a battle for the lead.